# Optional nested validation in vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

what is the correct way to add an optional validation object in vuelidate?

Given a validation shape of:

```
validations: {
    vehicles: {
        $each: {
            type: {
                required
            },
            engine: {
                required: requiredIf((vehicle) => vehicle.type == 'car'),

                size: {
                    required
                },

                power: {
                    required
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation was that for a vehicle of type `bike` I would not need to provide a size and power as their parent `engine` is not required. However the validation is returning invalid.

Comment: Can you include more of your implementation? Or at least what your model looks like?

Answer (score 3):

What you could do instead of asking for each subfield of engine to be required is to ask every engine to have both `size` and `power`, so that for everytime there is an engine it must have those keys. Add this together with the requiredIf and you have the following: `Every vehicle must have a type, if it is a car then an engine is required and every engine must have a power and size`.

The following snippet shows it working.

```js
Vue.use(vuelidate.default);
let { required, requiredIf, helpers } = validators;
const contains = (param) =>
  (value) => !helpers.req(value) ||
    param.reduce((accum, curr) => accum && curr in value, true);
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    vehicles: [
      {
        type: 'car',
        engine: {
          size: 5,
          power: 2.5,
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'bike',
      }
    ]
  }),
  validations: {
    vehicles: {
      $each: {
        type: { required },
        engine: {
          required: requiredIf((value) => value.type === 'car'),
          contains: contains(['size', 'power']),
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.$v.$invalid);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.5/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I think the downside to this solution is it removes validation rules for `size` and `power`.

Comment: @tony19 no it doesn't. All you have to do is to add them, the only thing you can't do is to put required. I haven't included any because the OP hasn't.

Comment: Yes, it does remove the rules for those two fields. You can confirm by looking at `$v` at runtime and seeing that there are no rules for `size` and `power`. The rules would be used to display errors to the user. If you try adding the rules, you'll end up with the same problem in the original question.

Comment: @tony19 So if I add a `size: { minValue: minValue(0) }` it won't work?

Comment: That seems to work in that it correctly raises an error if the field is missing. I suppose that could be a suitable replacement for `required` in this case. I think that rule should be added to your answer so that it covers the functionality originally shown in the question.

Comment: @tony19 Agreed, but the OP hasn't placed any other validation except for required, so there is no true replacement. We need the OP's say on this.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: My actual data is a little more complex than the example I gave. Not only would there be other validation rules for size and power, they also each have nested objects of there own. I might be better off validating each vehicle type separately in their respective child components to reduce the complexity of the vueliate config.

Comment: @sweetroll Can you share your schema so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar situation recently and resolved using 'parentVm', as documented at https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-accessing-component.

You should try this:

```
...

engine: {
  required: requiredIf((parentVm) => {return parentVm.type === 'car'}),
  size: {between: between(yourMinValue, yourMaxValue)},
  power: {between: between(yourMinValue, yourMaxValue)},
} 
...
```

Comment: Since your $v is a collection you must validate every item by use something like this:
<span v-if="$v.YourCollection.$each[index].YourCollectionItemField.$error" class="text-danger">Your Message here!</span>